# Geometry Nodes - How can I transfere UVs from on mesh to another?

Tags: modeling, uv, geometry-nodes

I currently have a project where I need to transfere uvs from one object to another. Both have the exact same topology and everthing, the only diffrence is the uv map. This need to be done in geomtry nodes.

Lets take this as an example, so I whant this:
[image]

To be like this;

[image]

I set upp this geomtry node setup and it is almost working.
[image]
But all the boundary loops are all wrong and seems to be still connected.
[image]

How can I solve this?
Here is a link to the .blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12aZ57PzoyCP4AJ6cS8NG2IdKatzOTJOh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you should not rely on the nodes like *Sample Nearest XXX* for *Face Corner* because sometimes, you are jumping from on UV island to the other. If everything is the same between both objects, including the face numbering and the face corner numbering, could you not just transfer UVMap value by index ?

Comment: Thanks StefLAncien! Using just index works! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

Assuming *Face(s)* index is the same, as well as *Face Corner(s)* index, a *Sample Index* node is enough:

[image: GN graph]