How to set vertex position to uv coordinates in blender?
The task is:
Firstly we assume that the world position of vertices to its uv coordinates is a bijection, that means our models guarantee that there's no two mesh share the same texture area, we could say that one world position map only one uv coordinates, and one uv coordinates map only one world position.
Then I want to obtain a picture whose pixels indicate the world position of it.
For example:
A chest and its original textures.


We simply set vertex shader output to uv coordiniate (just orthographic camera or directly
set clip space), and set fragment shader output to its world position, we could get the result.

But I'm not familiar with blender's geometry node, so I cannot achieve the same results as vertex shader. How can I set the position of geometry data to uv coordinates?
Maybe use a triangle instance? Is that too complex?
import bpy is ok. import bge to set shaders is not we prefers.


May I suggest to check the UV Debug group node in this post https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/315336/geometry-nodes-how-can-i-transfere-uvs-from-on-mesh-to-another ? As I understand your question, it is doing the job.

Thanks a lot. I got it!
